# El action de mi form no funciona en HTML

Tags: php, html5, formularios

Actualmente tengo un problema porque cree un formulario y dentro de mi etiqueta de form agregué un action, el problema radica en que no ejecuta la url de mi action, al momento de dar clic en mi botón de tipo submit, este no ejecuta ninguna acción y mi archivo `validar.php` si tiene funcionalidad correcta ya que por separado si me manda a la ruta de php, pero al implementarlo en mi proyecto ya no realiza la acción.

codigo de formulario:

```
<form action="login/validar.php" method="post" class="form"  role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                                        <div for="caja1" class="form-group">
                                             <label for="caja1" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
                                             <input type="text" id="caja1" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div for="caja2" class="form-group">
                                             <label for="caja2" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                                             <input type="password" id="caja2" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Entrar a...</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> Mantente conectado
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
```

código de complementación `index.php`:

```
<?php
include 'login/index.php';

?>
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN, CÓDIGO PARA validar.php

```
<?php

echo "entro 1";

session_start();

//verificar que el formulario se haya mandado 
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
    //si se mandó el formulario, consultar bd (utilizando una herencia 'include')
    include ('../db/conexion.php');
    //práctica de seguridad para para evitar ataques tipo injection
    $nombredeusuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usuario']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    //consultar a bd para ver si los datos corresponden a un registro 
    $comprobacion_nombre = 'select * from cdusuarioscliente where cUsuario = "' . $nombredeusuario . '"';
    //objetos, lo que hace es ejecutar la consulta
    $comprobacion = $conn->query($comprobacion_nombre);
    //objeto para ver si se obtuvo resultados, con una condición 
    if ($comprobacion->num_rows > 0) {
        //consulta contraseña de usuario
        $consulta_bd = mysqli_query($conn, 'select cContrasena from cdusuarioscliente where cUsuario = "' . $nombredeusuario . '"'); 
        //funcion para recoger dato
        $recoger_dato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_bd);
        //si hay más de 0 resultados se comprueba la contraseña
        $comprobar_password = password_verify($password, $recoger_dato['cContrasena']);
        //saber si la contraseña es correcta 
        if ($comprobar_password) {
            //variable de sesion 
            $_SESSION['cUsuario'] = $nombredeusuario;
            header('location: ./');
        } else {
            print 'Los datos han sido incorrectos <br> <a href="./">Volver</a>';
        }
    } else {
        print 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos <br> <a href="./">Volver</a>';
    }
} else {
    //redireccionar a la pagina de inicio 
    header('location: ./');
}
?>
```

Comment: no tienes un .js con algo como event.preventDefault();

Comment: @JackNavaRow  La verdad no estoy segura, ya que agregué varias librerías que tenían archivos .js y no sé si dentro esté ese evento, ¿causa algún problema si existe el evento event.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: El código que pusiste no tiene ningún problema para enviar el formulario. Revisa si tienes JS que interfiere con el funcionamiento de la página. Busca también otros tags **form** que puedas tener abiertos o mejor valida el HTML, si esta correcto desactiva JS y prueba de nuevo, casi seguro que es una de estas dos cosas.

Comment: chequea el enlace https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ cuando tienes esa funcion de jQuery no habilita el submit

Comment: quita el id="login-nav" y pruebalo

Comment: Pero cuando aprietas el botón ¿se carga otra página o no hace nada? Lo que se hace normalmente, después de apretar el botón, es recuperar en JavaScript (o jQuey u otro) los valores del formulario para hacer algo con ellos.

Comment: @Cedano no realiza ninguna acción :(

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo de **action="login/validar.php"**

Comment: @gilbertoquintero ya actualicé el comentario donde agrego el código de validar.php

Comment: @gilbertoquintero ya actualicé

Comment: @Orici Cómo sé cuando los formularios chocan?

Comment: @SeliGVyo te recomiendo que lo primero que conectes en tu script php es la conexion ala bd

Comment: @JackNavaRow No encontré el evento que me dijiste event.preventDefault();  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tu problema se debe a que estas utilizando la etiqueta button en vez de la etiqueta input, ya que si agregaste muchas librerías estas pudieron afectar el funcionamiento de dicha etiqueta en tu proyecto.

```
<input type="submit" name="prueba" placeholder="ingrese algo aqui" />
```

Comment: Podrías explicar la parte sobre `button` siendo más propensa a errores de envío que la etiqueta `input`. ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: Gracias, si fue por eso. También tengo la misma duda que @Alvaro Montoro

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro a lo que me refiero es que en este caso las posibles librerías o plugins que agrego a su proyecto pudieron haber modificado la etiqueta de button y por ende suprimir su atributo type="submit" y una alternativa fue modificar esa etiqueta por otra que posiblemente no haya sido afectada